# Android App Crash GSL MEM ERROR, how to decipher from logcat

Tags: java, android, logcat

My android application crashes after some time of usage.  I can't seem to get anything useful out of the logcat file.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to figure out the cause from this?  The app starts to show black squares all over the place and then eventually crashes.  I've attached the logcat file, or at least as much of it that it buffered because once the error started, the logging rate increased dramatically.

```html
_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.064 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.064 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.064 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <oglLinkEGLImage2GLTexture:2083>: @ err: invalid operation
04-14 19:53:18.064 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateImageKHR:4830>: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
04-14 19:53:18.064 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_definition.cc(176)] eglCreateImageKHR for cross-thread sharing failed: 0x300c
04-14 19:53:18.065 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.065 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.066 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.066 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.066 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <oglLinkEGLImage2GLTexture:2083>: @ err: invalid operation
04-14 19:53:18.066 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateImageKHR:4830>: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
04-14 19:53:18.066 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_definition.cc(176)] eglCreateImageKHR for cross-thread sharing failed: 0x300c
04-14 19:53:18.067 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.067 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.068 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.068 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.068 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <oglLinkEGLImage2GLTexture:2083>: @ err: invalid operation
04-14 19:53:18.068 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateImageKHR:4830>: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
04-14 19:53:18.069 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_definition.cc(176)] eglCreateImageKHR for cross-thread sharing failed: 0x300c
04-14 19:53:18.069 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/chromium: [ERROR:gles2_cmd_decoder.cc(2774)] [.RenderWorker-0x8ed69500.GpuRasterization]GL ERROR :GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY : BackFramebuffer::Destroy: <- error from previous GL command
04-14 19:53:18.072 8525-8673/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glTexSubImage2D:562>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
04-14 19:53:18.074 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.075 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.082 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.082 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.083 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.083 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.083 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <oglLinkEGLImage2GLTexture:2083>: @ err: invalid operation
04-14 19:53:18.083 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateImageKHR:4830>: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
04-14 19:53:18.083 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_definition.cc(176)] eglCreateImageKHR for cross-thread sharing failed: 0x300c
04-14 19:53:18.090 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.090 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.091 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.091 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.092 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.092 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.092 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glTexImage2D:501>: GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
04-14 19:53:18.093 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.093 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.093 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.094 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.094 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <oglLinkEGLImage2GLTexture:2083>: @ err: invalid operation
04-14 19:53:18.094 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateImageKHR:4830>: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
04-14 19:53:18.094 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_definition.cc(176)] eglCreateImageKHR for cross-thread sharing failed: 0x300c
04-14 19:53:18.095 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.095 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.095 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.096 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.096 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <oglLinkEGLImage2GLTexture:2083>: @ err: invalid operation
04-14 19:53:18.096 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateImageKHR:4830>: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
04-14 19:53:18.096 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_definition.cc(176)] eglCreateImageKHR for cross-thread sharing failed: 0x300c
04-14 19:53:18.097 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.097 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.097 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.097 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.098 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <oglLinkEGLImage2GLTexture:2083>: @ err: invalid operation
04-14 19:53:18.098 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateImageKHR:4830>: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
04-14 19:53:18.098 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_definition.cc(176)] eglCreateImageKHR for cross-thread sharing failed: 0x300c
04-14 19:53:18.099 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.100 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.101 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.102 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.102 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.102 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.103 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.103 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.103 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <oglLinkEGLImage2GLTexture:2083>: @ err: invalid operation
04-14 19:53:18.103 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateImageKHR:4830>: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
04-14 19:53:18.103 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/chromium: [ERROR:texture_definition.cc(176)] eglCreateImageKHR for cross-thread sharing failed: 0x300c
04-14 19:53:18.104 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.104 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.104 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:18.105 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:18.105 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <oglLinkEGLImage2GLTexture:2083>: @ err: invalid operation
04-14 19:53:18.105 8525-8688/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglCreateImageKHR:4830>: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER

*Edited to remove redundancy

04-14 19:53:36.078 8525-8673/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:36.079 8525-8673/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:36.081 8525-8673/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpuobj_alloc:2337>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
04-14 19:53:36.081 8525-8673/com.myapp.android.myappname E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:2203>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
04-14 19:53:36.081 8525-8673/com.myapp.android.myappname W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glTexImage2D:501>: GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY
04-14 19:53:36.081 8525-8673/com.myapp.android.myappname E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  Out of memory!
04-14 19:53:36.081 8525-8673/com.myapp.android.myappname A/OpenGLRenderer: glTexImage2D error! GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY (0x505)
                                                                                          
                                                                                          --------- beginning of crash
04-14 19:53:36.140 8525-8673/com.myapp.android.myappname A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 8673 (RenderThread), pid 8525 (d.myappname)
04-14 19:53:41.276 8525-8673/com.myapp.android.myappname A/libc: crash_dump helper failed to exec
```

Comment: I met this issue too. Have you found the solution?